# Using a WPF control template from a program library in a WPF project

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, templates, dll

I have a program library in which I have control templates for WPF controls. Now I want to include or use this program library as a .dll in another WPF project.
Is it possible to use these control templates from the library in the XAML of the WPF project?

If yes, how do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Define your control templates in a resource dictionary in a WPF Class Library or similar
- Add a reference to the class library from the WPF application project
- Reference the resource dictionary using a pack URI in the `App.xaml.cs` class of the WPF application:

  ```
    <Application x:Class="WpfApp1.App"
                 xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                 xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
                 StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
        <Application.Resources>
            <ResourceDictionary>
                <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                    <ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/YourClassLibrary;component/YourResourceDictionary.xaml"
                </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            </ResourceDictionary>
        </Application.Resources>
    </Application>
  ```

You should then be able to reference any resource in the resource dictionary in the class library as usual.